# SSE/neon support for Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, arm, sse, neon, apple-silicon

I'm trying to get my app ready for Apple Silicon. My app currently uses SSE instructions for Mac and equivalent Neon implementation for iOS.

Apple porting guide suggests moving to the Accelerate framework, which I'm not ready to do right now.

Is there a way to keep using SSE/neon (based on the architecture) in the universal binary for Apple silicon? I can see that arm64_neon.h is not available for Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NEON intrinsics are available via the `arm_neon.h` header, and are standard [ARM C Language Extensions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0053/latest/) intrinsics. `arm64_neon.h` is a MSVC specific header name (and since a few versions of MSVC, you can use the standard header name `arm_neon.h` for both 32 and 64 bit ARM even there, like other compilers).